# SMART error (CurrentPendingSector) and (OfflineUncorrectableSector)

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl, smart, smartmontools

I have been receiving the following error messages every day for several months now, and I do not know how to stop receiving these messages.

`CurrentPendingSector`

```
This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

   host name:  myhost
   DNS domain: [Empty]

The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 6 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors

Device info:
KingFast, S/N:03112222C0002, FW:U0803A0, 256 GB

For details see host's SYSLOG.

You can also use the smartctl utility for further investigation.
The original message about this issue was sent at Fri Feb  3 19:41:29 2023 PST
Another message will be sent in 24 hours if the problem persists.
```

`OfflineUncorrectableSector`

```
This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

   host name:  myhost
   DNS domain: [Empty]

The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 3 Offline uncorrectable sectors

Device info:
KingFast, S/N:03112222C0002, FW:U0803A0, 256 GB

For details see host's SYSLOG.

You can also use the smartctl utility for further investigation.
The original message about this issue was sent at Fri Feb  3 19:41:29 2023 PST
Another message will be sent in 24 hours if the problem persists.
```

`smartctl -a /dev/sda`

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.19.0-46-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     KingFast
Serial Number:    03112222C0002
Firmware Version: U0803A0
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jul  8 15:44:59 2023 PDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3335
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       440
160 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
161 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       86
163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       26
164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       79004
165 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       481
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       114
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       5050
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       98
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       88
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       35
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       86
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       168900
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       815543
245 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       191939

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3329         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3325         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3321         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3313         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3309         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3306         -
# 7  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3250         -
# 8  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3232         -
# 9  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3229         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       976         -
#11  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       968         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

I have tried to ignore the `197` and `198` errors in `/etc/smartd.conf` with

```
/dev/sda -d removable -n standby -H -l error -l selftest -f -t -I 197 -I 198 -s (S/../.././(01|09|17)|L/../../3/11) -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
```

to no avail.

I also do not see any `LBA_of_first_error` in the self-test section.

To me, it appears that `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED`  is healthy and the self-tests return no errors. My current understanding is that the disk appears to be healthy but is still sending these messages erroneously.

Is there something that I'm missing?

The `/dev/sda` drive is a KingFast 256 GB SSD, and I'm not sure if this would be relevant as I could not find anything online for this particular drive or manufacturer.

How would I be able to stop receiving these messages but still have SMART monitoring for other genuine issues on the drive, and how would I fix the issue if this error message really does indicate some problem with the drive?

Thanks!

Edit:

After running `smartctl -t long /dev/sda`, I have

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.19.0-46-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     KingFast
Serial Number:    03112222C0002
Firmware Version: U0803A0
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jul  9 10:05:33 2023 PDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x03) Offline data collection activity
                    is in progress.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 241) Self-test routine in progress...
                    10% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  600) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0002) Does not save SMART data before
                    entering power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3341
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       441
160 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
161 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       86
163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       26
164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       79553
165 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       482
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       115
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       5050
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       98
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       88
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       46
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       6
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       3
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       86
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       170468
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   100   100   050    Old_age   Offline      -       815560
245 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       193199

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3337         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3329         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3325         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3321         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3313         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3309         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3306         -
# 8  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3250         -
# 9  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3232         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3229         -
#11  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       976         -
#12  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%       968         -

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

The #12 Extended offline test `Completed without error`, so I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do from here.

**Edit #2:**

I have also run the following which I believe indicate that there are no errors with the drive:

```
badblocks -sv /dev/sda
Checking blocks 0 to 250059095
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=64K conv=noerror
3907173+1 records in
3907173+1 records out
256060514304 bytes (256 GB, 238 GiB) copied, 485.648 s, 527 MB/s
```

Comment: Please try running `smartctl -t long /dev/device`

Comment: I have run the `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` as requested, and it appears to me that the test completed without any errors. I'm not really sure what to do at this point because from my understanding, the device appears to not have any physical problems.

Comment: I have also ran badblocks on `/dev/sda`: ```badblocks -sv /dev/sda
Checking blocks 0 to 250059095
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to suppress the messages by adding `-C 197+ -U 198+`.
I think the issue is with my particular brand of SSD.